# google search console figures not matching when adding filters

Tags: search, console, google-search-console

i have a situation where it seems data between queries and page tabs in google dont seem  to ad dup correctly.

i have a filter on

```
search type = 'web', 
date range = '01-jul-2019 to 28-jul-2019', 
query = 'word1 word2 word3'
```

in the query tab i get

```
query                       clicks      impressions

'word1 word2 word3'           11           13
```

in page tab i get various pages but one is (and this already exceeds the query totals)

```
'http://webpage1.com.au'      13           14
```

when i add an additional filter on webpage1.com.au exact match then the query tab changes itself to

```
query                       clicks      impressions

'word1 word2 word3'           13           14
```

1.) why does query tabs totals < pages when they should be the same, they are the inverse of each other.

2.) how does adding a filter increases the query values from 11 and 13 to 13 and 14, and thus becoming correct.

I have either missed something, or GSC figures are buggy. i did google but couldn't find a lot. thanks